# Continuity, constant functions

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

I am completely stuck and would be delighted if someone could explain an approach. Thanks!

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $f (x) = f (x^2)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Show that $f(y^{(2^{-n})})=f(y)$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}$ (the natural numbers including zero) and $y ≥ 0$ and conclude that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You need to show some kind of attempt. For example, it's obvious that the relation on $y$ holds when $n=0$. Have you tried thinking about what happens when $n=1$?

Comment: welcome to MSE. is this edition true ?

Comment: The question has two parts. First showing that the relation holds. The second part is using it to prove that f is constant. Do you have a problem with both?

Comment: well $f(x)=f(\sqrt{x})=f(\sqrt{\sqrt{x}})$ can you continue ?

Comment: The edition is true.

Comment: I was hoping to get a better suggestion or solution.

Answer (score 1):

First observe that $f(x)=f(x^2)=f(-x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, because $(-x)^2=x^2$.

Let $x>0$, then $x^{\frac1{2^n}}\to x^0=1$ if $n\to\infty$, so the constant sequence $f(x)=f(x^{\frac12})=f(x^{\frac14})=\dots$ converges to $f(1)$ by continuity, so we must have $f(x)=f(1)$.

Finally, continuity at $0$ implies $f(0)=f(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for you for your answer! How can i conclude that  f  is constant?

Comment: For every $x$, I proved $f(x)=f(1)$.